# Apache redirect based on host and uri

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a fairly simple redirect rule setup in my `Apache vhost`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mobile.foo.com
    ServerAlias *.foo.com

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.foo\.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mobile.bar.com/foo [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to add another condition based on the request uri. The redirect above should not be performed if the request uri equals `google.html`. I guess another rewrite condition is needed based on the request uri variable. Any ideas on how the `regex` should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/google\.html$
```